# What is the ideal time to perform tharpanam?

Tags: rituals, practice, amavasya

What is the best time to perform Amavasya Tharpanam?
Is there any specific reason why it should be done at that time ?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Agastiar.org](http://www.agasthiar.org/a/tharpanam.htm) website **sunrise** and **noon** are the  recommended times of the day to perform Pitru Tarpana.

> **When to do Tharpanam?**
>
> Sathguru Venkataraman said that **according to Maha Guru Agasthiar,
>   tharpanam should be done at sunrise.**
>    There is a tradition that says that tharpanam should be done at noon.
>   If this is your tradition, please do follow that.

**Is there any specific reason why it should be done at that time ?**

As you can see no such reasons are specified.

EDIT

As per the Katyayana Smriti noon is the best time.Evening is not recommended at all.

> A Sraddha in which Pindas are to be offered for the gratification for
>   a month, is to be preferably performed on the wane of the Moon
>   (Amavasya-day) ; **it should be performed in the third part of the day,
>   but never towards the evening,**.
>
> **Katyayana Smriti,Chapter 16**